# Geolocation has been disabled in this document by Feature Policy

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps, ionic-framework, ionic3

In my ionic app, I am trying to use google maps. When I was using below code then it did show maps on my page.

```
let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.9290, 138.6010);

let mapOptions = {
  center: latLng,
  zoom: 15,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}

this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement.nativeElement, mapOptions);
```

But when I use below code, then I get

> `Geolocation has been disabled in this document by Feature Policy` error.

```
this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((position) => {

  let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

  let mapOptions = {
    center: latLng,
    zoom: 15,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }

  this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement.nativeElement, mapOptions);

}, (err) => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: are you using an Iframe?

Comment: No I am not. I am using `<div #map id="map"></div> ` in template.

Comment: Are you serving over SSL?

Comment: I am serving on localhost right now.

Comment: Anyone who can help??

Comment: Regarding of this [page](https://docs.apppresser.com/article/418-iframe-geolocation-feature-policy), this problem causes you use geolocation api in iframe page.

Comment: @ZafarSaleem I am facing same issue. If I run app in localhost it works, but in real apk adn ionic builder it fails

Answer (score 0):

Take a look a this: 
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation#ios-quirks, maybe it can help you too.

I am using the OpenStreetMap (not Google Maps) but the problem occurring it is the same, it must exist an entry in your *-Info.plist (in case of iOS), so for that, you have to add the following lines at your config.xml (cordova project):

```
<edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" target="NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription">
   <string>We want your location! Best regards NSA</string>
</edit-config>
```

You can also check this geolocation plugin https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/geolocation/, as it could be used with Google Maps or OpenStreetMap, but... that doesn't change the fact that you have to add some information(message) to let the mobile's user know why (and when) your app needs permission to access the user's location.

Another thing... yet... it won't work with the command combination:

```
ionic serve --lab -c
```

The problem will persist, I still didn't find out if there's a way to fix that too.
But the solution above should solve the problem using emulator or the device itself. (Of course, without the --lab option, that is, in Desktop browser testing mode, the problem do not exist either)

Another option to test how the things are working (after the config.xml modification) is to use the Ionic Dev App ([iOs](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ionic-devapp/id1233447133?mt=8) or [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.ionic.devapp&hl=en)), it could allow the test be done directly at the iPhone, for instance.

[image: Ionic Dev App at iPhone testing geolocation]
[image]

Hope it helps something.